# Is [Pre-Populates, Pre Populates, Prepopulates] a word?

Tags: orthography, hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

**[Pre-Populates, Pre Populates,  Prepopulates]**

Simple at first but after some research I can't actually find much on this.

**Background/Context**: I need to write some sort of tech specification and the app takes in data from an external source (API) and prepopulates a few fields. It came up with a red underline saying I had misspelled something and couldn't find it in the drop-down. I then searched online and a few different sources say different things.
I'd like to know if this is actually a word or it's just accepted by a wide range of the population

**Limited research:**
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/populate
No record of prepopulate; only has these
outpopulate, outpopulated, outpopulating repopulate, repopulated, repopulating superpopulated, underpopulate, underpopulated, underpopulating

https://www.yourdictionary.com/prepopulate
Very limited description
Includes these
prepopulated

- prepopulates
- prepopulating

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prepopulate

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=prepopulate
No record

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prepopulate
Thought it might be US only
No record

Comment: Your links to Your Dictionary and Wiktionary say it's a computing term, so it's not necessarily in generalist dictionaries. The question "is it a word" isn't very meaningful. In a computing context, it will probably be understood, but if you're writing for a non-technical audience, it's a bit more complex, and if you're told not to use words that aren't in a (specific) dictionary then you can't use it. You could find alternatives like "populated in advance" if you're worried.

Comment: Not really worried, just more curious to be honest. Although I'm a software engineer do you know of it's use elsewhere?

Comment: It seems to be largely a recent usage, as shown in [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prepopulate%2Cprepopulates%2Cprepopulated%2Cpre-populate%2Cpre-populates%2Cpre-populated&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), though there were a few earlier examples.  The meaning (*previously populated* or metaphorically *already given values* etc.) seems obvious

Comment: If it's not in Wiktionary, one ought to be extremely wary about using a candidate word. If it is, but not in say OED, wary. This is in Wiktionary, but as the [computing] caveat is appended, back to 'extremely wary' for broadened usage.

Comment: If you're using *prepopulated*, you're in good company from your nonhyphenated list in dictionary.com/.../populate.

Comment: The word I've always heard used for that is "propagate," not "pre-populate," like if you're filling out a form on an app and the app already has your name and address stored, instead of asking you to rekey that information in the various fields, it "propagates" it, meaning it's automatically filled in those fields for you so that you can skip over them, usually with an option to change them if need be.

Comment: Thanks for that @BenjaminHarman; what about in the context of non-computing, e.g I've prepopulated your name on this form, you just need to fill in the rest, could you use propagates?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes,** "prepopulate" (also spelled "pre-populate") is a word *in the field of computing.* Since it's a piece of technical jargon, you won't find it in most dictionaries and spelling checkers may highlight it. Wiktionary lists the word, as you have noted, but it correctly states that this word is only used in computing.

You can find plenty of examples on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=prepopulated&s=f288b880-4242-4629-87b1-aa1a337e8bb2), [GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=prepopulate&type=Code), *et cetera.*

Comment: Thanks, i made a comment above also - What about in the context of non-computing, e.g (I've  "prepopulated" your name on this form, you just need to fill in the rest). Is the word strictly in the field of computing, as personally I would rather say "I've filled in your name..."

Comment: @ShaunMoore As I stated, the term is not used outside of the field.